# Returning mapped attributes in keycloak to express

Tags: express, ldap, keycloak

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522154/get-username-from-keycloak-session-in-nodejs) and I'm able to return firstname, lastname, username, and email without issues. I'm trying to map our LDAP using the keycloak mapping directory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678883/keycloak-retrieve-custom-attributes-to-keycloakprincipal). I'm succesful at getting LDAP fields to a

Here is a working example of a express router that returns keycloak data after a succesful login. I see I'm [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279711/mapping-ldap-member-memberof-attributes-into-keycloak) the only one using the attributes to map LDAP data.

The question: How can I get userdetail information from keycloak from these custom attributes (mappings) into an express server? I don't think its documented.

```html
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.kauth.grant.access_token.content);

  res.render("index", {
    title: "FORM-ARWD",
    username: req.kauth.grant.access_token.content.preferred_username,
    firstname: req.kauth.grant.access_token.content.given_name,
    lastname: req.kauth.grant.access_token.content.family_name,
    email: req.kauth.grant.access_token.content.email,
    city: req.kauth.grant.access_token.content.l
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get additional attributes inside the backend you need to map them in keycloak settings like this and then you will get them from `req.kauth.grant.access_token.content` ([reed more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678883/keycloak-retrieve-custom-attributes-to-keycloakprincipal)):

[image]

[image]