# NodeJS keycloak get user Informations

Tags: node.js, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a web app with Angular in Frontend, NodeJS in Backend and Keycloak as an identity management solution.

My Frontend stores the access- and id-token. All the NodeJS routes are protected by keycloak (bearer only). That's why I intercepted on each of my requests the access-token as bearer in the header:

```
setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.oauthService.getAccessToken() }
```

Now I'm able to authorize the requests, but how I can get the user Information in Backend?

At least only an ID is necessary to make user-dependent DB requests. Is it possible to get any information from the access token?

Or does the NodeJS connector (keycloak-connect) get this information itself so that I can save it in a session? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I am not wrong, Access token is JWT token and you will be able to decode is as bellow:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var tokendetails = jwt.decode(token)
```

Alternatively in Keycloakconnect  middleware, you can get details as below

```
app.get('/apis/me', keycloak.enforcer('user:profile', {response_mode: 'token'}), function (req, res) {
       ​let  tokenDetails = req.kauth.grant

   ​})
```

I have not tested so I am not 100% sure but I think you should be able to get username this way:

```
req.kauth.grant.access_token.content.preferred_username
```

Another way you could to something like this:

```
const request = require('request');
const options = {
  url: `${authServerUrl}/realms/${encodeURIComponent(realm)}/account`;,
  headers: {
    'Authorization':'bearer '+token
  }
};

request(options,function(error, response, body){

   if(!error) { 
    let userProfile = body
   }
})
```

Below resources might help you :
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_nodejs_adapter
https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/lib/keyCloakService.js

Comment: also, check this out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522154/get-username-from-keycloak-session-in-nodejs