# Receiving data from Keycloak session on NodeJs

Tags: node.js, jwt, authorization, keycloak

I have an app written in NodeJS and I am using Keycloak as an indentity provider. I would like to get username of currently logged user, and it is possible as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522154/get-username-from-keycloak-session-in-nodejs). But, I can only fetch this object when I send a request.

```
app.get('/protected-resource', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => {
  const token = req.kauth.grant.access_token;
  console.log('JWT Token:', token); // Log the JWT token
  res.send(`JWT Token: ${token}`);
});
```

I want to get username in the moment when a user fill their credentials and press login button on the frontend.
Is this the only way how I can access the username? Or keycloak has some kind of in build logs which I can use?

I am using [keycloak-connect package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect?activeTab=readme) but I wasn't able to find any kind of logs which I will be able to use.